# Intuitive Explanation for Distribution of Sum of Independent Discrete Uniform Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

So apparently the distribution of the sum of i.i.d discrete uniform random variables on $\lbrace 0,1,2,...,k \rbrace$ is given by this:

[PMF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4sOa.png)

$$P(Y=y) = \frac{1}{(k+1)^n}{n \choose y}_{k+1},\;y = \{0,1,\dots,nk\}$$

Can somebody please give an intuitive explanation for this?  I'm not quite sure how to interpret it or why the Gaussian Binomial Coefficient is used.

Answer (score 0):

$$P\Big(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{U_i=x_i\}\Big)=\prod_{i=1}^nP(U_i=x_i)=\frac1{(k+1)^n}$$ where $x_i\in\{0,1,2,\cdots,k\}$. Now $$P\Big(\sum_{i=1}^nU_i=y\Big)=\sum_{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=y}P\Big(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{U_i=x_i\}\Big)$$
Now the number of $n$-tuples $(x_1,\cdots, x_n)$ satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=y$ with the constraint $0\le x_i\le k$ is given by $\binom{n}{y}_{k+1}$